# How to model dependency between input features when building a classifier

Tags: classification, python, svm, feature-engineering

I have dataset with the shape of (1000,20) (1000 rows, 20 features) and I want to build a classifier for it. However, most sk-learn algorithms assume the these 20 features are independent. In my features, there is a gaussian dependency between the features. How can I model this dependency as an input for a classifier like SVM or ExtraTreeClassifier?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "independent" and "gaussian dependency"?  The reason for asking is that extremely few methods assume all features are independent: that rare condition holds exclusively for certain kinds of experiments.  Thus, although I am unfamiliar with the sk-learn algorithms, I strongly doubt many (if any at all) assume independence in the usual statistical sense.

Comment: @whuber OK , I mean that I know for certain that they are related and this dependecy can be modeled by a function; Now , my aim is to model it in order to improve classification. Does it make sense?